# Is it possible in Jersey to have access to an injected HttpServletRequest, instead of to a proxy

Tags: java, rest, dependency-injection, proxy, jersey

When injecting `HttpServletRequest` in Jersey/JAX-RS resources, the injected value is a proxy. E.g.:

```
@Path("/myResource") 
class MyResource {
    @Inject 
    HttpServletRequest request;
    ...
}
```

Will inject a `Proxy` object for the requested `HttpServletRequest`. I need access to the actual `HttpServletRequest` instance object, because I want to use some container specific features that are not in the proxied `HttpServletRequest`  interface.

Is there a way in jersey to have access to the actual object via injection? I know that in older versions of Jersey you could inject a `ThreadLocal<HttpServletRequest>` to achieve this. But that doesn't seem to be supported in jersey 2.15 anymore.

Rationale: My code depends on functionality in `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request` which implements `HttpRequest`, and adds functionality for HTTP/2 push. I would like to use that with Jersey/JAX-RS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't make your resource class a singleton. If you do this, there is no choice but to proxy, as the request is in a different scope.

```
@Singleton
@Path("servlet")
public class ServletResource {

    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;

    @GET
    public String getType() {
        return request.getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

With `@Singleton`

> `C:\>curl http://localhost:8080/api/servlet`
>   `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41`

Without `@Singleton`

> `C:\>curl http://localhost:8080/api/servlet`
>   `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request`

There are other ways your class can become a singleton, like registering it as an instance

You can aslo inject it as a method parameter. Singleton or not, you will get the actual instance

```
@GET
public String getType(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getClass().getName();
}
```

---

**See Also**

- [Injecting Request Scoped Objects into Singleton Scoped Object with HK2 and Jersey](http://paulsamsotha.blogspot.com/2015/12/injecting-request-scoped-objects-into.html)

Answer (score 0):

As Op said that

> I know that in older versions of Jersey you could inject a ThreadLocal to achieve this.

I just want to add some code here which could implement this for those who are still using an older version of jersey like I do:

```
@Context ThreadLocal<HttpServletRequest> treq;
```

And a link for this:[Thread access to @Context objects?](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Thread-access-to-Context-objects-td3880758.html)
Hope that would help.