# @Context returns Proxy instead of HttpServletRequest despite not using Singleton scope

Tags: jersey, guice, embedded-jetty

Getting method not found error on trying to access request.getServletContext(), also HttpServletRequest is always a proxy object

### Resource class

```
// also tried @RequestScoped
@Path("/res")
public class ProdController {
    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;



    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Response getProductList() {
            System.out.println(request.getClass());
            // this always prints class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34
            // when I try to access request.getServletContext(); it always shows method not found error

            // more code goes here
    }
```

### Binder Module

```
public class ApplicationBinderModule extends ServletModule {
    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        bind(ProdController.class);
        serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class);

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try binding the servlet as `Singleton`?        `bind(ProdController.class).asEagerSingleton();`

Comment: Yes I tried it but it gives the same error.

Comment: This could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29434312/is-it-possible-in-jersey-to-have-access-to-an-injected-httpservletrequest-inste